# Async method populating XAML binded fields inconsistently

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a view which is populated by two different *Models*. For my app this means that two differences *Services* are used to obtain the data for these respective models.

Now the data simply will not populate. What do I mean? Currently, when the page loads only `Group.Name` shows. The rest of the `User` labels do not show. I have to create a button which changes a field in the `User` binded object before the three labels show.

**Note:** `BaseViewModel` inherits  `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IPageLifecycleAware`. `SetProperty()` raises the event for when the property is changed.

#### View

```
<StackLayout Margin="10" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding User.Name}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding User.Age}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding User.Occupation}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Group.Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class ProfileViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IGroupService _groupService;
    private IUserService _userService;
    public ProfileViewModel(IGroupService groupService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _groupService = groupService;
        _userService = userService;
        GetUser();
        GetGroup();
    }

    private async void GetUser()
    {
        var user = await _userService.GetUserAsync();
        User = user;
        SetProfilePhoto();
    }

    private async void GetGroup()
    {
        var group = await _groupService.GetGroupAsync();
        Group = group;
    }

    private void SetProfilePhoto()
    {
        var profilePhotoBytes = User.ProfilePhotoBytes;
        if (profilePhotoBytes == null || profilePhotoBytes.Length == 0)
            ProfilePhoto = ImageSource.FromResource("MyApp.Images.default_profile_picture.png");
        else
            ProfilePhoto = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(profilePhotoBytes));
    }

    private ImageSource _profilePhoto;
    public ImageSource ProfilePhoto { get => _profilePhoto; set => SetProperty(ref _profilePhoto, value); }

    private User _user;
    public User User { get => _user; set => SetProperty(ref _user, value); 
    }
    private Group _group;
    public Group Group{ get => _group; set => SetProperty(ref _group, value); }
}
```

#### Models

```
public class User: BindableBase
{
    private string _id;
    public string Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }

    private string _name;
    public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }

    private string _age;
    public string Age { get => _age; set => SetProperty(ref _age, value); }

    private string _occupation;
    public string Occupation { get => _occupation; set => SetProperty(ref _occupation, value); }

    private byte[] _profilePhotoBytes;
    public byte[] ProfilePhotoBytes { get => _profilePhotoBytes; set => SetProperty(ref _profilePhotoBytes, value); }

    private ImageSource _profilePhoto;
    public ImageSource ProfilePhoto { get => _profilePhoto; set => SetProperty(ref _profilePhoto, value); }
}

public class Group: BindableBase
{
    private string _id;
    public string Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }

    private string _name;
    public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }

    private byte[] _groupPhotoBytes;
    public byte[] GroupPhotoBytes { get => _groupPhotoBytes; set => SetProperty(ref _groupPhotoBytes, value); }

    private string _createdUserId;
    public string CreatedUserId { get => _createdUserId; set => SetProperty(ref _createdUserId, value); }

    private DateTime _createdDate;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get => _createdDate; set => SetProperty(ref _createdDate, value); }
}
```

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have just realised that when I comment out `ProfilePhotoBytes` from being set through `bytes` in the else statement this resolves the issue. I have tested this 15 times to make sure it is consistent. This means that operation somehow interferes with the rest of the `User` object being notified to the front end. Any help with this please?

Comment: Please make a breakpoint to debug the profilePhotoBytes whether it get the value.

Comment: It definitely gets a value, because the photo gets set and then the text doesn;'t. But then if it goes to default photo then both the photo and text shows. I noticed that lower resolution photos do not have this issue. Its interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be simple...

As you are binding class properties to UI elements which are not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface...any changes to those properties which not reflect your UI elements post UI elements has been already rendered...

The easiest fix would be Implement your model class with

> INotifyPropertyChanged

interface...

As you are using Prism this can be achieved by inheriting

> BindableBase

class...for eg

```
public class Group : BindableBase
{
    string _id;
    public string Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    string _name;
    public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }

    public byte[] GroupPhotoBytes { get; set; } //change similarly like above
    public string CreatedUserId { get; set; } // to do 
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } // to do
}
```

After the above changes done...now your UI will be updated when your properties are updated...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I agree that should be there. Anyway, it still does not populate my view. I actually have to created a button and change a property of User because the rest of the data loads. I have updated the models so you can see exactly what I am working with. I have updated the question to reflect the issue. Thanks.